# How to force Invalid Bearer token in web api?

Tags: c#, web-applications, user-accounts

I had to delete over 90 users in my web api.
I am using web api 2 individual account.
But after deleting this users, they still can use my web-api, because access token are cached somewhere.
How to prevent that?

Comment: I thought about Bearer token. 
Its just typo. Sorry for my english

Comment: Did anyone found solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because tokens are stored on the client and not on the server, u can't manually invalid token.

but i found three solutions:
1'st - Just wait until tokens expire (14 days, it was too long for me)
2'nd - changing the date on the server, when i add'ed 14 days to server date, All tokens expired (but on production server this was unacceptable)
3'rd - Changing machine key on server.

Comment: reinstall windows

Comment: or may be buy a new server?