# Making Bearer token expire manually

Tags: asp.net-web-api, bearer-token

I have a Web API which is issuing Bearer Token after successful login check.
And API is set with Token Expiration time as 1 day and its working fine.

What I want is to expire a that token before its scheduled time (like 1 hour) if user sends a log out request, so that token won't work after that.

Is it possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24552448/web-api-2-owin-authentication-signout-doesnt-logout

Answer (score 0):

As per my point of view, there is no need to expire generated token manually. Though you want to do so, you need to update(*refresh*) token expire time to the current request time, make sense?

But in that case, you will need to create a new token every time even if user logout and login before expiration time.

Answer (score 0):

Because tokens are stored on the client and not on the server, You can't manually invalid token.
I had similar problem once, [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24044558/how-to-force-invalid-bearer-token-in-web-api)